How does the first stanza of Robert Burns's "For a' that and a' that" translate into modern English?
I want to like this poem, but I guess I'm too dense to make sense of the first stanza, mainly because (I suppose) of Burns's dialect:

Is there, for honest poverty,
That hangs his head, and a’ that?
The coward-slave, we pass him by,
We dare be poor for a’ that!
For a’ that, and a’ that,
Our toils obscure, and a’ that;
The rank is but the guinea’s stamp,
The man’s the gowd for a’ that!

Is there ... that hangs his head?  Coward-slave?  Pass him by?  Dare be poor?  Our toils obscure?  etc. etc.  I'm sorry, I'm just not getting it.  I understand the general gist of the poem but I am trying to make sense of the particulars.

I agree that the first two lines don't seem to form a coherent sentence. The gist is that even a poor man can be proud of his humble employment (toils obscure) and ignores people who behave like cowards or slaves. High rank is like the stamp that makes a lump of gold into a coin, but the gold is still valuable without it. (That's my understanding as an Englishwoman!)

I'll not post it here, but ChatGPT makes a good translation into modern English. It's a very Calvinistic view that hard work makes the man. Also, I guess that "coward-slave" might be rendered as "wage-slave" in modern parlance.

@KenY-N  I don't think I would have ever thought to go to ChatGPT for poetry!  Not sure how to feel about that!  :)  Anyway, did take a look.  Very helpful.  Thanks!

The difficult word is “that” at the start of the second line, which is a pronoun meaning “the thing which” or (in this case) “the person who”, not a conjugation introducing a relative clause. In modern English we would use “anyone who”:

Is there, for honest poverty, anyone who hangs his head, and all that?

This person hangs their head in shame for their poverty, and makes other gestures or acts of humility (“all that”). But the poet describes the poverty as “honest”, meaning that they earn their living honestly and not by crime, so why should they be ashamed? Such a person, Burns says, is a “coward” (afraid to hold their head up) and a “slave” (subservient to those of higher social rank). It is better, the poet says, to “dare to be poor”, that is, to dare to be proud despite one’s poverty.
The “toils” in line 6 are the labours that the poor are obliged to do for their sustenance; they are “obscure” in the sense “lowly, humble, undistinguished”.
The last two lines are a metaphor comparing social rank to “gowd” (gold) coinage. A guinea was a gold coin, and coins are made by stamping circular metal blanks in a die or “stamp” that impresses the design into the metal. The poet says that social rank is like the stamp that presses gold into a guinea coin: it does not change the value of the metal, only the outward design.
Update A commenter asked for an explanation of the title and refrain, “for a’ that and a’ that”. The word “a’” is Scots for “all”, so this consists of two phrases:

for all that despite the fact that, notwithstanding that, although.
and all that and all that sort of thing, and so forth, et cetera (frequently implying a diffident or dismissive attitude on the part of the speaker).
Oxford English Dictionary.

For example, in the second line, when the poet asks whether anyone “hangs his head, and all that”, we should take “all that” to be all the other gestures of humility that poor people may feel obliged to make; the use of the phrase implies both solidarity with the reader (“I don’t need to list them all, since you know them just as well as I do”) and an attitude of dismissiveness (“there’s no point in listing them since they are cowardly and slavish”).
And in the fourth line, “We dare be poor for all that!”, the poet means that we dare to be poor and proud, despite all other considerations, and in particular, despite the social pressure to be ashamed of one’s poverty.
Update 2 The OP asked for advice about which references to consult when trying to understand Burns. The only reference work I used when writing this answer was the Oxford English Dictionary. Burns wrote in 18th-century Scots, not in 21st-century English, so whenever a phrase or sentence seems difficult or wrong in context, I check the dictionary to see if I have got the wrong sense of a word. In this poem, the first sentence appears to be ungrammatical, which often indicates that a common functional word has been misunderstood, and it was not too hard to identify “that” as the culprit. (Compare this question, where “of” was the difficult word, or this one, where it was “but”.)
Update 3 Commenter Ken Y-N suggested (based on a ChatGPT query) that Burns might be referring to the Protestant work ethic, that is, he is saying that the poor should be proud because of their “toils obscure”. I don’t think this interpretation stands up when we look at the whole poem: in particular, in the fourth stanza the qualities listed by the poet are honesty, good faith, “pith of sense” and “pride of worth”, and not work ethic. Burns wrote the poem in 1795, in the wake of the French Revolution and the Declaration of the Rights of Man and of the Citizen, so that an appeal to inherent human dignity seems more likely.
Large language models like ChatGPT are not to be trusted because they produce output that is statistically similar to the corpus they were trained on. But when interpreting a poem, we don’t want a typical or average interpretation, we want an interpretation that is specific to the details of the poem.

Is it possible to answer the question, by saying what "For a' that, and a' that" means?

I think "obscure" here also carries an additional, more literal, aspect of "out of sight", as with various house servants using separate entrances, staircases, passageways, etc.

Well, that makes all the sense in the world!  Thank you very much!  I tried hard to find something like this on the internet to no avail.  Any recommendations on references?  Thanks again!

@user1271772 I've added an explanation of the title.

@bob.sacamento You're welcome! I've added an update explaining how I went about it and which reference I used.

Just as a note, I based the Protestant work ethic bit on my own knowledge as a Scot brought up in a traditional Protestant god-fearing environment, and confirming that Burns himself subscribed to this Calvinistic viewpoint. I agree that I should have used "plausible" rather than "good" to describe ChatGPT's output.
